# Pi 400 key cap replacements

Tags: keyboard, pi-400

I ordered 6 raspberry pi400s for my class of elementary school students a couple of months ago. Already some of the key caps have broken off and I’m sure this is going to continue. I’m looking for the manufacturer of the key caps so I can just buy a big bag of spares. I contacted the raspberry pi foundation and raspberry pi Ltd, the Sony factory in Wales and got no help. I’ve seen these keys on other compact keyboards (Anker A7726? Elecom ‎TK-FBP102SV/EC? E-win ‎EW-B009?) so they must be off the shelf components. Just to head off some suggestions I received previously: I can’t and don’t want to 3D print anything. I don’t want to buy an official raspberry pi keyboard as a donor. I don’t want to configure another key to work as the missing key. I don’t want to buy another keyboard and connect it to my pi400. Thanks for reading!

Comment: did you manage to find any replacement keys? My daughter managed to break a few of her keys.

Comment: No. But I will answer my own question if I find some.

Answer (score 0):

The Anker A7726 keycaps are NOT compatible with the RPi400 keyboard.
Source - ebay supplier selling individual keycaps for the A7726 showed a picture of the underlying key capture mechanism.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/134185)